# Combining arrays with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

To check how often an equal value is in my array I count them with:

```
$count = array_count_values($array_names);
```

To get each key/value pair I use this foreach loop:

```
foreach ($count as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . '–' . $key . '<br />'; 
}
```

Possible output:

```
2 – Harry Peters
1 – Winston Meyers
3 – Jason Williams
```

Now I’ve got a second array with URLs:

```
$urls = array(http://harry-peters.com, http://winston-meyers.com, http://jason-williams.com);
```

That array should be wrapped around the `$key` variable like

```
echo $value . '- <a href="' . $url . '">' . $key . '</a><br />';
```

So I’ll get something like:

```
2 – <a href="http://harry-peters.com">Harry Peters</a>
1 – <a href="http://winston-meyers.com">Winston Meyers</a>
3 – <a href="http://jason-williams.com">Jason Williams</a>
```

But I don’t know how to implement another foreach loop for the URLs to the first loop.

Comment: How that second array is related to the first one? Can you show some examples of input arrays and expected output?

Comment: yeah, i don't know what you mean by second array or urls, sample input and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: You can simply use the `count()` function to count the number of elements in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this useful for you?

```
<?php

$names = array
(
    2 => "Harry Peters",
    1 => "Winston Meyers",
    3 => "Jason Williams"
);

$urls = array
(
    "http://harry-peters.com", 
    "http://winston-meyers.com", 
    "http://jason-williams.com"
);

$counter = 0;

foreach ($names as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . '- <a href="' . $urls[$counter] . '">' . $value . '</a><br />';

    $counter++;
}
```

Be careful because the urls have to be exactly matching the order of the names.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $count =array("mark Ortiz", "You", "me", "hello");
  $urls = array("http://harry-peters.com", "http://winston-meyers.com", "http://jason-williams.com")
    foreach ($count as $key => $value) {
    //echo $key . '-' . $value . '<br />'; 
    $count[$key] = "<a href='$urls[$key]' >".$value."</a>";// this forced value to be formatted
    }
    foreach ($count as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . '-' . $value . '<br />'; 

    }
```

that should be easy and i hope you be carefull if ever to avoid array Index out of bound exception